# Block certain urls on Draytek 2820n

Tags: router, draytek

I am trying to block certain URL's on my Draytek 2820n router, but am having trouble making it work.

Can someone give the steps to setting up blocking www.ebay.co.uk please.

Also, can you then let certain IP's circumvent these rules?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the "URL content filter" on the Firewall tab.  Use the "Enable URL Access Control" section and enter the URLs or partial URLs that you want blocked eg *ebay* will block *ebay.co.uk*, *members.ebay.com* and so on.

To exclude certain IPs from this filtering you will firstly need to create two "pretend" subnets and bind the MAC addresses of the trusted PCs to the first subnet and the untrusted to the second.  For example your LAN is 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 - even though we are not subnetting it for the puposes of the block we are prentending to. So the first subnet is 192.168.1.1-127 and the second is 192.168.1.128-254

You then need to enable "Enable Excepting Subnets" and enter 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.128.  This will exclude from the filtering all addresses between 192.168.0.1-127

You can of course change the subnet sizes to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This article on the DrayTek user forums may be helpful (registration required):

> [Exclude subnet or ip from webcontent filtering (DrayTek Forums)](http://www.forum.draytek.co.uk/viewtopic.php?t=12172&highlight=content+filter)

I think if you want to have an exception for specific IP addresses you add the IP address and a subnet mask of 255.255.255.255.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a web proxy instead. That allows fine grained control over web access and it keeps a log of who has been to what sites, which can be very useful when confronting the malefactors with the evidence of their misdeeds :-)

There's an open source web proxy called SQUID that is very good.

JR